# Gitlab Debian Repository Public Key is Not Available

Tags: debian, apt, gitlab

When running 'sudo apt update' I get the following error:

```
user@gitlab:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Get:6 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/debian stretch InRelease [23.3 kB]
Err:6 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/debian stretch InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3F01618A51312F3F
Fetched 23.3 kB in 2s (11.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/debian stretch InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3F01618A51312F3F
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3F01618A51312F3F
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the key installed by the Gitlab installation script has expired. This can be verified by running `sudo apt-key list`

```
user@gitlab:~$ sudo apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2015-04-17 [SC] [expired: 2020-04-15]
      1A4C 919D B987 D435 9396  38B9 1421 9A96 E15E 78F4
uid           [ expired] GitLab B.V. (package repository signing key) <packages@gitlab.com>
-------Output Snipped----------
```

This is easily fixed by running the same command that [the Gitlab installation script](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/install) runs, which will fetch the new key from Gitlab and install it in the APT keyring.

```
curl -L "https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/gpgkey" 2> /dev/null | sudo apt-key add - &>/dev/null
```

After this, the `apt-key list` command can be rerun to verify that the key was installed properly.

```
user@gitlab:~$ sudo apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2015-04-17 [SC] [expired: 2020-04-15]
      1A4C 919D B987 D435 9396  38B9 1421 9A96 E15E 78F4
uid           [ expired] GitLab B.V. (package repository signing key) <packages@gitlab.com>

pub   rsa4096 2020-03-02 [SC] [expires: 2022-03-02]
      F640 3F65 44A3 8863 DAA0  B6E0 3F01 618A 5131 2F3F
uid           [ unknown] GitLab B.V. (package repository signing key) <packages@gitlab.com>
sub   rsa4096 2020-03-02 [E] [expires: 2022-03-02]
```

Comment: +1, this was super helpful. Thanks for sharing. Here is [a blog](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/03/30/gpg-key-for-gitlab-package-repositories-metadata-changing/) that Gitlab put out about the new key.

Comment: Cheers mate, I had to fix this previously for another repository, but at the time I couldn't find anything concrete on how to do it specifically for Gitlab, so I thought I'd document it here if somebody else runs into the same problem!

Comment: The relevant GitLab document can be found here: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/update/package_signatures#fetching-new-keys-after-2020-04-06